# Confused with API signatures public and private key pairs

Tags: php, encryption, ssl

I have created an API that needs authorising with a signed request.

I am using the the php openssl_sign and openssl_verify functions.
I understand the concept of the public and private key (DSA algorithm). But basically I have no idea in how to implement it.

I am working from this example from http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-sign.php

```
<?php
$data = "Beeeeer is really good.. hic...";

// You can get a simple private/public key pair using:
// openssl genrsa 512 >private_key.txt
// openssl rsa -pubout <private_key.txt >public_key.txt

// IMPORTANT: The key pair below is provided for testing only. 
// For security reasons you must get a new key pair
// for production use, obviously.

$private_key = <<<EOD
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY----- 
MIIBOgIBAAJBANDiE2+Xi/WnO+s120NiiJhNyIButVu6zxqlVzz0wy2j4kQVUC4Z
RZD80IY+4wIiX2YxKBZKGnd2TtPkcJ/ljkUCAwEAAQJAL151ZeMKHEU2c1qdRKS9
sTxCcc2pVwoAGVzRccNX16tfmCf8FjxuM3WmLdsPxYoHrwb1LFNxiNk1MXrxjH3R
6QIhAPB7edmcjH4bhMaJBztcbNE1VRCEi/bisAwiPPMq9/2nAiEA3lyc5+f6DEIJ
h1y6BWkdVULDSM+jpi1XiV/DevxuijMCIQCAEPGqHsF+4v7Jj+3HAgh9PU6otj2n
Y79nJtCYmvhoHwIgNDePaS4inApN7omp7WdXyhPZhBmulnGDYvEoGJN66d0CIHra
I2SvDkQ5CmrzkW5qPaE2oO7BSqAhRZxiYpZFb5CI
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
EOD;
$public_key = <<<EOD
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MFwwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADSwAwSAJBANDiE2+Xi/WnO+s120NiiJhNyIButVu6
zxqlVzz0wy2j4kQVUC4ZRZD80IY+4wIiX2YxKBZKGnd2TtPkcJ/ljkUCAwEAAQ==
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
EOD;

$binary_signature = "";

// At least with PHP 5.2.2 / OpenSSL 0.9.8b (Fedora 7)
// there seems to be no need to call openssl_get_privatekey or similar.
// Just pass the key as defined above
openssl_sign($data, $binary_signature, $private_key, OPENSSL_ALGO_SHA1);

// Check signature
$ok = openssl_verify($data, $binary_signature, $public_key, OPENSSL_ALGO_SHA1);
echo "check #1: ";
if ($ok == 1) {
    echo "signature ok (as it should be)\n";
 } elseif ($ok == 0) {
    echo "bad (there's something wrong)\n";
} else {
    echo "ugly, error checking signature\n";
}

$ok = openssl_verify('tampered'.$data, $binary_signature, $public_key,     OPENSSL_ALGO_SHA1);
echo "check #2: ";
if ($ok == 1) {
    echo "ERROR: Data has been tampered, but signature is still valid! Argh!\n";
} elseif ($ok == 0) {
    echo "bad signature (as it should be, since data has beent tampered)\n";
} else {
    echo "ugly, error checking signature\n";
}
?>
```

But I am strugling to undestand how this could be implemented into a URI request.

The private and public keys seem quite large to be used in http get requests and also how would the client be able to generate a signature that could be verifed by the server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically here are 3 things in encryption:

1. Generation of Public key and **pair** of Private keys
2. Encrypt the data with Private key 1 and Public key
3. Decrypt the data with Public key and Private key 2

The step 1 happens only one time, you can generate public key (or keys [RSA]) and private keys for two clients (or a server and client)

Before you send data you need to sign the data with your private key (only known for you) and public key (known for both), this will create a cypertext (or it is called digest), and you can send this to the opposite person (other client or server). At the other side, they Decrypt the cypertext with the public key , then with their private key to retrieve actual data.

This is actually the basics of Encryption-Decryption with public private keys.

Various versions of these encryption and decryption are available, doing a wikipedia will be helpful.

Comment: Wikipedia can be a bit over complicated in its explanation, sometimes you just need to understand the concept.  Thanks

Comment: @Sajith Amma,  You mention a pair of private keys above.  How can one public key unlock two separate private keys?  I was under the impression that a public and private key relationship was one to one.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like not a good idea to transfer the key together with a HTTP get request which you want to sign.

Better have the public key already stored at the server side (for example, in a client database), and look it up from some identifier sent with the request (e.g. the user name).

Your request URL would look like this:

```
rtp://api.example.com/username=User1&method=XML&product=shoes&size=5&sex=male&signature=x1cvGgtRfJs4FgG
```

The client would use the private key (and any DSA implementation) to sign the important part of the request URL.

(The private key should never transfered at all.)